# ASP.NET Model Id in ViewModel - is it safe?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, model, mapping, viewmodel

Scenario:
(with an ASP.NET web app - Core or MVC)

I have a database with `Users` and `Items` for each user.
That means the `UserId` is a `foreign key` in the `Items` table.

From the browser I login as a `User`. I get my `Items` as a list of `ItemViewModels`, which are mapped (AutoMapper) to `ItemViewModels` via a simple api GET request.

I want to update one of the items (which should belong to me - the logged in user) via a simple API call. So I send the modified item back to the server via a PUT request as an `ItemViewModel`.

> First approach:

The simplest approach would be to include the Item's database ID, `ItemId`, in the `ItemViewModel` - so when I receive the item to be updated as an `ItemViewModel`, I can map it back to the existing item in the database.

This however sounds pretty unsafe to me, as anyone could modify the PUT request with any `ItemId` and affect items which don't belong to the user who executed the request. Is there anything I'm missing about this approach?

> Second approach:

Don't pass the database PK `ItemId` in the `ItemViewModel`.
Instead use an additional form of identification: let's say that user `X` has 10 items. And they are numbered from 1 to 10 using a property named `UserItemId`(which also exists in the database).

I can then pass this `UserItemId` in the `ItemViewModel` and when I get it back I can map it to an existing Item in the database (if all was ok with the request) or discard it and reject the request if the `UserItemId` didn't match anything from the logged in user's items.

Is anyone using this approach?

**Pros**:

The user only has access to it's own items and can't affect anyone else's since it doesn't know the actual Item ID (primary key), and any modifications are restricted to it's items.

**Cons**:

A great deal of extra management must be implemented on the server side for this approach to work.

> Any other approaches ?

Please consider that the case mentioned above applies to all entities in the database which a client side implementation can CRUD, so it's not just the simple case described above.

The proposed solution should work for the entire app data.

I know this question has been asked [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260176/in-asp-net-mvc-should-the-view-models-have-an-id) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938721/storing-model-id-in-asp-net-mvc-viewmodel-security-issues) but the first one doesn't have a satisfying answer and I don't think the second one really applies to my situation, since it just deals with the UserId.

Thanks.

> EDIT

Please consider the `Item` above as an aggregate root which contains multiple complex `subItems` each with a table in the db. And the question applies for them as much as for the main `Item`. That means that each `subItem` is passed as a ViewModel to the client.

I should mention that regarding further securing the update request:

1. For the first approach I can easily check if the user is allowed to change the item. But I should do this for all `subItems` too.
2. For the second approach I can check if the user can update the `Item` as follows: I get the `userItemId` of the incoming ViewModel -> I get all the logged in user's items from the database and try to find a match with the same `userItemId`, if I get a hit then I proceed with the update.

Comment: Never trust user input. You must **always** validate on the server. Check that the current user has permission to update the object based on its ID, and only if they have, perform the update (otherwise redirect to an error page)

Answer (score 0):

I think your application is not secure, if you only hide the Id.
You must check, before changing the database entity, if the user is allowed to change the entity. 
In your case you should check, if your `Id` from the authenticated user is the `UserId` in your item.
If your ViewModel ist similar or identical for your API you could use a FilterAttribute in your controller.